# Connecting delay on local network (SYN RETRANSMISSION)

Tags: networking, router, tcp

Somebody knows what could be the issue?

More often than not I can not connect instantly to my IP camera or local server and have a initial delay of around 10 seconds before it connects to the camera (software/browser) both from pc or phone, or to the server via ssh.

Here is my network (everything is wired except phones):

My main ISP router is at 192.168.100.1, the camera and server are connected to that router.

```
IP camera at 192.168.100.42
server at 192.168.100.55
```

I have a second openwrt router at 192.168.1.1 that is connected to the main one with its wan being 192.168.100.100, my PC and phones are using that router only.

```
PC at 192.168.1.10
```

I made a capture on the openwrt router and when I launch the camera app for example it sends SYN packets to it but doesnt get any replies for like 10 seconds, same happens with the server via ssh.

Capture: https://imgur.com/a/6mzdgAS

Do I need to manually add a route on the main or openwrt router or something else? The weird thing is that it sometimes works normally, and sometimes not usually after not connecting for some time.

Comment: It would be interesting to check whether those SYNs are sent to the correct _MAC address_ – highlight each and take a look at the "packet details" section; could it be that they're initially sent to MAC A until eventually ARP makes them go to MAC B?

Comment: Checked, the destination MAC seems correct https://imgur.com/a/fzJBmBu
Is it allowed to attach the .pcap here? I have both the problematic and normal working ones

Comment: Its entirely possible that the camera is sufficiently busy that it can't provide capacity for the connection immediately. just a thought.

Comment: @FrankThomas highly unlikely as it records only motion and there isnt many, and it wouldnt explain the same happening with the server that sits doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

What seems to fixed it is adding a static arp entry on the openwrt router for the camera but with the MAC of the main ISP router, with the actual camera MAC it would work for short time but then wouldnt connect at all.

```
ip neigh change 192.168.100.40 lladdr 30:e9:8e:ae:33:18 nud permanent dev eth0.2
```